# Script to copy workbook to workbook data only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Script would run in the source workbook.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1yeS6_qhURUYHVkImLNMjdGUeMWhPDwQKdLNgpygiwG4'); // sss = source spreadsheet

 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ss = source sheet

 //Get full range of data

 var SRange = ss.getDataRange();

 //get A1 notation identifying the range

 var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();

 //get the data values in range

 var SData = SRange.getValues();



var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KQBsMJ0vgBQwkM89d166RPyVahIZY3DRSOWVCB4zapE'); // tss = target spreadsheet

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var first = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

sheet.clear({ formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true });



 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1KQBsMJ0vgBQwkM89d166RPyVahIZY3DRSOWVCB4zapE');

 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // ts = target sheet

 //set the target range to the values of the source data

 ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);

}
```

Would set to trigger on form submit. Would copy the data from a sheet in one workbook to a sheet in another workbook. Format of both sheets will be same AND must remain unaltered. Row & column count/size will be same on each sheet.

Comment: You need to edit this question so that your code is properly blocked. In the editor, select the code and then hit the button at top with {}.

Comment: Importrange() function of spreadsheet does not fit your need ?

Comment: it takes too long - want to see if a script reduces time (6 mins)

Answer (score 0):

Here a code that will go through all the sheet of your source workbook and copy data in the current workbook. Sheet name will be the same of source spreadsheet and only data are copied.

EDIT : Code changed to not copy but import data from spreadsheet to a dest spreadsheet where we assume that the sheet is already created. If sheet does not exist we create it.

```
function importWorkBook(){
  var idSource = "IdOfTheSheetSource";
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(idSource).getSheets();
  var current = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  for(var i in sheets){
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var destSheet = current.getSheetByName(sheet.getName());
    if(destSheet){
      destSheet.getRange(1,1,destSheet.getMaxRows(),destSheet.getMaxColumns()).clearContent();
      destSheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
      Logger.log(sheet.getName() + " imported");
    }else{
      var newSheet = current.insertSheet(sheet.getName());
      newSheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
      Logger.log(sheet.getName() + " created");
    }
  }
}
```

Stéphane

Comment: Hi Stéphane -  Script should copy the data from a single sheet in one workbook to a single sheet in another workbook. 
I tried to put sheet names into your script - but it gave error on run 
[ A sheet with the name "Sheet1" already exists.]

Format of both sheets must remain unaltered.

Comment: Yes it is impossible to have in one workbook 2 sheets with the same name. If you can't change source name or copy name it is impossible to do what you want. In other case update the script depending your preference, script works.

Comment: Hi St3ph
the sheets are in different workbooks  - -

need to script to copy from the source to the destination ( data only )

Comment: I change the code because it was not clear that you want to import data in the corresponding sheet and not copy the sheet. Now if sheet exist data is copied it not sheet is created with data.